# I'm getting two errors on start react native project

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, bundle

error 1

"Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly"

error 2

after error 1 press Reload(R,R)

[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90egH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try running these inside project directory for the BundleBridge issue:

1. react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &
2. mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
3. curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"

For error 2, try

> adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

After the react-native run-android command has completed, then retry R+R

Comment: Both fixes not working?
Do you see a device when you run `adb devices`?

Comment: Yes . Yes I see my device

Comment: This helped, except in my case I just needed to run `react-native start` in the background before running `react-native run-android`.